# MD4 Message Digest - What are x y and z?

Tags: encryption, md5

I've read the following pdf document http://cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/ns/docs/kaufman/04hash.pdf (starting at page 16 )

I think I've understand everything, but I couldn't figure out what x y and z in the functions are. Could anybody tell me which bits are meant with that?

Comment: You seem to have the same problem as the students mentioned in [How do I convince my students that the choice of variable of integration is irrelevant?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646238/how-do-i-convince-my-students-that-the-choice-of-variable-of-integration-is-irre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `F(x, y, z)` in MD4 operates on 32-bit words, not bits, and is used as part of the round to generate a value that is XORed with part of the digest. It could be expressed in C as:

```
uint32_t F(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z)
{
    return (x & y) | (~x ^ z);
}
```

As used in MD4, `x`, `y`, and `z` represent three chunks of the digest being computed, but that's not inherent to the function. Just keep reading the definition of the algorithm to see how it's used.